# What is a Debian based distribution?

Tags: linux, node.js, debian

I'm running through an AngularJS tutorial, and in the [get started](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial#get-started) section it says:

> In Debian based distributions, there is a name clash with another
>   utility called node. The suggested solution is to also install the
>   nodejs-legacy apt package, which renames node to nodejs.
>
> - apt-get install nodejs-legacy npm
> - nodejs --version
> - npm --version

I don't understand what a Debian based distribution means, even after going to https://packages.debian.org/sid/nodejs-legacy

As a side note, I've used Angular and Node before in other tutorials, so I am not sure if I should follow this get-started part. I'm sort of going with it now because I installed nvm without intending to or understanding what it is for.

Comment: Do you know what [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) actually is?

Comment: Debian is a flavour of Linux, named after a guy called Ian and a gal called Deborah.

Comment: Debain is a distribution of the Linux kernel and includes Ubuntu. Basically it sounds like it has a root tool that is also called node. This could lead to issues if you are trying to call nodejs so they created th more explicit executable name.

Comment: See the info tab of the Debian Tag -- http://stackoverflow.com/tags/debian/info

Comment: @Marty No, not really. I looked it up in the context it was given, with respect to "nodejs-legacy". It's frustrating, really, to come across an undefined term like this in a tutorial, and not know if it applies to me or not.

Comment: @Jackie How would you know you have a Debian based distribution?

Comment: If you're not using Debian why worry about it?

Comment: @PhilipK Whether it's something I should worry about is what I don't know. I don't know if I'm using a Debian distribution or not. I'm trying to follow a tutorial and it mentions lots of new terms I haven't come across before. Most of the tutorial applies to me, but it's unclear is if this part of the tutorial applies to me too. So, I'm investigating by asking.

Comment: @user70848 You could try to type apt-get and see if the command is found. That is probably the easiest way.

Comment: @Jackie No, it's not found. What does that mean? (But, I see 'apt-get' a lot.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely if the Linux distribution is using **dpkg** and using the **apt** package manager you could consider it a Debian Based distribution ie Debian/Ubuntu. There are quite a few, you can see a list here...

https://www.debian.org/misc/children-distros

Wikipedia has a good page with more details on Linux distributions. The Debian list can be found here...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#Debian-based

It's worth clicking on the image to see just how many distributions Debian has spawned.